# mostrar imagen de carga

Tags: angularjs, ionic, controller

mostrar una imagen de carga o un mensaje de cargando mientras cargan todos los productos traídos del controlador

```
.controller('productosCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, $location, $ionicLoading, Productos) {
    Productos.productos().then(function(argument, $timeout) {
        $scope.producto = []
        for (var i = 0; i <= argument.store.products.length - 1; i++) {
            $scope.producto.push({
                id: argument.store.products[i].id,
                name: argument.store.products[i].name,
                description: argument.store.products[i].description,
                category: argument.store.products[i].category,
                store: argument.store.products[i].store,
                price: argument.store.products[i].price,
                picture: argument.store.products[i].picture.picture.url
            });
            console.log(i);
        }
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    })
})
```

los imprimo en la vista con un ng repeat, pero quiero q antes de cargar la imagen me muestre una imagen estatica antes o un mensaje de cargando porque hay veces q carga muy lento

Comment: Tu pregunta es de hace unos días, ¿has conseguido solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar una imagen de carga simplemente haz lo siguiente:

Lo primero, tienes que agregar el siguiente import:

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Después, en el constructor de la clase, declaras lo siguiente:

```
constructor(..., public loading: LoadingController, ...){...}
```

Ahora, en el momento que lo quieras mostrar sólo tienes que hacerlo así:

```
let loader = this.loading.create({  //Creamos la imagen de carga
  content: 'Cargando equipos...',
});

loader.present();  //Mostramos la carga
```

Para cerrar la imagen de la carga, tenemos que ejecutar este código:

```
loader.dismissAll();
```

Así es como lo utilizo yo en Ionic, en la parte de Typescript

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar la el ngif else, [Aqui la pagina.](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Ejemplo:

```
<div *ngIf="productos async;else cargando">
  contenido cuando cargue productos
</div>

<ng-template #cargando>
  <img src="../imagenes/imagencargando.png">
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

No tengo certeza cuanto puede demorar la carga de tus datos, pero esto deberia poder ayudarte.

```
.controller('productosCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, $location, $ionicLoading, Productos) {


        $ionicLoading.show({
             //puede ser android o ios
             template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"/>'
        });
        Productos.productos().then(function(argument, $timeout) {
            $scope.producto = []
            for (var i = 0; i <= argument.store.products.length - 1; i++) {
                $scope.producto.push({
                    id: argument.store.products[i].id,
                    name: argument.store.products[i].name,
                    description: argument.store.products[i].description,
                    category: argument.store.products[i].category,
                    store: argument.store.products[i].store,
                    price: argument.store.products[i].price,
                    picture: argument.store.products[i].picture.picture.url
                });
                console.log(i);
            }
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        })
    })
```

Comment: No necesitas crear los métodos `$scope.show` y `$scope.hide` para llamar al Factory `$ionicLoading` a menos que planees usarlos en la vista con algo como `ng-click="show()"` en tu caso particular puedes llamar los métodos directamente :)

Comment: Perfecto!, puede que ambos casos sean validos!, yo prefiero dejarlo en funciones por eso deje tambien este codigo, aunque el puede hacerlo de la manera que guste. :)

Comment: Mi punto es que el `$scope` es la *fuente de la verdad* y llenarlo de objetos y funciones innecesarios sería el equivalente de crear capas de abstracción sin un motivo que lo justifique. Es posible pero usualmente no recomendado. Si no lo vas a usar en la vista de alguna forma llama al Factory directamente, no hay necesidad de complicar el código. Si dicho método hiciera alguna operación más complicada y necesitas reutilizar ese código varias veces *entonces* si sería buena idea crearlos.